# How do I get notification of a drive being powered on?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-foundation, diskarbitration

I have a problem on OS X, where if a drive is plugged in while powered off, and then powered on, I don't receive notification that a new disk has appeared. I do receive notification if I plug in a drive that is already powered on.

Currently, I'm registering callbacks for when a disk appears, disappears, or the description changes via disk arbitration (`DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback` et al). I don't see any other callbacks that might cover the scenario of a drive being turned on.

How do I receive notification when a drive that is already plugged in gets powered on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSWorkspace` provides a notification, `NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification`, when a disk is mounted. In outline you declare a notification handler, for example:

```
- (void) mountNotify:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   // extract details from notification
   NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
   NSString *volumeMounted = userInfo[@"NSDevicePath"];
   NSString *volumeDisplayName = userInfo[@"NSWorkspaceVolumeLocalizedNameKey"];

   if (volumeMounted != nil)
   {
       // volume has been mounted
   }
}
```

and register for notifications:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(mountNotify:)
     name:NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification
     object:nil
];
```

There is also a similar notification, `NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification`, for when a disk is unmounted.

For more details see Apple's [`NSWorkspace` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIEFIDI).

HTH.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this in C++?

Comment: @dauphic - Well Objective-C++ is clearly one answer. If you want a C function level interface then what you are using appears to be it. However you're getting a strange error with that. Whether a disk is powered on or not when connected to your computer should make no difference. There is a distinction between attaching a device and mounting one, though the two are normally linked. If you have not tested using approval or other callbacks you might want to look into that.